# How can I write content to an empty xml elements

Tags: c#, xml, tags

I want to write to an XML file and be able to save it. The user will edit it from a gridview. I have loaded the file, and now I want to write to it. 
I am writing my empty elements value, comment and font. The date will get updated every time you change the date or add values

```
 XmlDocument _doc = new XmlDocument();
 _doc.Load(outputFilePath);
```

Here is the XML:

```
<data name="FinEnrolment_CurrentSelectedUser_Label" xml:space="preserve">
<value></value>
<comment>[Font][/Font][DateStamp][/DateStamp][Comment][/Comment]</comment>
</data>
<data name="FinEnrolment_Exit_Button" xml:space="preserve">
<value></value>
<comment>[Font][/Font][DateStamp][/DateStamp][Comment][/Comment]</comment>
</data>
<data name="FinEnrolment_Exit_Verify_Message" xml:space="preserve">
<value></value>
<comment>[Font][/Font][DateStamp][/DateStamp][Comment][/Comment]</comment>
</data>
```

Comment: Can we see the code you use to write data?

Comment: Why are you using your own custom markup scheme in XML? Instead of using a string like `"[DateStamp][/DateStamp]"`, wouldn't it be sensible to have an actual XML element like `<DateStamp />`? That's what XML is all about, after all.

Comment: at  Ivaylo Slavov, Yes you can